# Facebook iframe(likebox) bottom cutoff

Tags: html, css, facebook

This seems to happen in all browsers but Opera and IE10 (yay for Opera and IE10?)
http://jsfiddle.net/puh67/

Css:

```
.Facebook,
.Facebook iframe
{
    height: 400px;
}​
```

Html:

```
<div class="Facebook">
  <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FFriskisSvettis-Landskrona%2F299504533446227&width=292&height=395&show_faces=false&colorscheme=light&stream=true&border_color&header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>​
```

[image]

Comment: Was this fixed in the end? As I can't seem anything wrong in most browsers, unless you set height to anything below <= 385px, even then, most of the CSS is enforced within the Facebook's iframe anyway :z

Comment: @MackieeE In the end i solved this by changing the height=395 parameter in the url, im not happy with the solution as i can't change it from CSS, but its better then nothing!

Answer (score -1):

i will suggest to use javascript to resize the iframe size once the page if fully loaded...

```
$("#frame")[0].setAttribute("height", "200");
```